# remove "." from end of column names in R

Tags: r

Dataset is of the form below. The columns with dates end with "." . I want to remove them, Please suggest an efficient way of doing this as the no of columns is huge.

The resultant dataset should not have the "." character at the end of columns which have dates as header.

```
Product   1/1/2020.     1/1/2019.   1/1/2018.      
   1          10          11          10          
   2          24          12           0           
   3          40          10          24            
   4          90           9           1            
   5          21           9           1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is called `df` you can use regex to remove the last "." in the column names. Try :

```
names(df) <- sub('\\.$', '', names(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `dplyr` `rename_with` for this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "\\.$"))
```